# Как в контроллере вызвать через фасад свойство из объекта сервиса?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

Везде в документации описано,как вызывать методы сервиса через фасад. А мне нужно вызвать свойство. Как это сделать на примере сервиса TestService?

```
namespace App\Folder\TestService;

class TestService
{
   public $test;
   public function __construct(){
     $this->test='123';
}
```

Comment: Объявить метод, который возвращает это свойство.

Comment: Обязательно через метод все должно проходить?нельзя попроще?

Comment: Можно, конечно. Выкинуть ларку и простыню спагетти кода написать.

Comment: Дело в том что свойство уже задано в конструкторе и соответственно по умолчанию будет и в объекте сервиса, зачем создавать метод когда нужно просто получить это свойство из объекта через фасад?

Comment: Потому что блин один из столпов ООП это __инкапсуляция__. Сделали смотрящий наружу метод и все, все остальные с ним работают, не подозревая что происходит внутри.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
namespace App\Folder\TestService;

class TestService
{
    private $test;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->test = '123';
    }

    public function getTest()
    {
        return $this->test;
    }

    /**
     * @param $var
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setTest($var)
    {
        $this->test = $var;

        return $this;
    }
}

$service = new TestService();
echo $service->getTest();
```

Comment: Нужен фасад и сервиспровайдер. Ну ладно, я почти разобрался